# How can I run curl and prompt for a password when running from npm?

Tags: node.js, curl, npm-init

I'm working on a Node.js file to automatically create a new Github repo.

When I run `curl -u 'BretCameron' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"test_repo"}'` in the terminal, it asks me for my GitHub password and then creates the new repo.

But I can't get this to work in Node, even though the `git` commands in my sample code are working fine:

```
const { exec, execSync } = require('child_process');

function run(func) {
 console.log(execSync(func).toString())
}

run('touch README.md');
run('git init');
run('git add README.md');
run('git commit -m "First commit"');
exec(`curl -u 'BretCameron' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"test_repo"}'`));
```

I have tried with the `exec` and `execSync` functions from the `child_process` module, as well as putting it into my helper function `run`. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Why would you need to? You can make requests from Node directly.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to put this into a `.npm-init.js` file, so that a GitHub repository is created automatically when running `npm init`

Comment: Do you want it to actually prompt for the credentials interactively? That seems like a problematic thing to run automatically.

Comment: If possible, yes!

Comment: How do you know that wherever you're running `npm init` from actually has an interactive terminal attached? What do you want to have happen if it doesn't have a terminal? What about if it has a stdin pipe, but not an attached tty/pty and so it can't set the terminal into noecho mode?